# CSS How do I force a container to be displayed underneath a preceding container whose elements float left

Tags: css

I want the div which displays "D" to appear beneath that one which displays "A" so that divs with matching background colours appear stacked over one another. However, I am getting this:

[image]

Where exactly in my CSS code must I clear my float?

```css
#container {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 990px;
}
#left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
#splitter {
  background-color: green;
  width: 90px;
  float: left;
}
#right {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">A</div>
  <div id="splitter">B</div>
  <div id="right">C</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">D</div>
  <div id="splitter">E</div>
  <div id="right">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did u tried display:block

Comment: Where do I insert it?

Comment: i posted the answer plz check it @rvelbon

Comment: try checking on my answer bro ..here are the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p4domjrb/ https://jsfiddle.net/p4domjrb/1/

Comment: You cannot have two elements with the same value for the `id` attribute within the same document. `id` must be unique per document.

Comment: use class instead reusing same id and learn to deal with floats :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context  https://css-tricks.com/search-results/?q=float

Answer (score 1):

Clear the floats in the container.
You have 3 simple ways to do that:

**1. Float**

```
#container {
  clear: both;
}
```

**2. Overflow**

```
#container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**3. Micro clearfix hack**

[Link](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

Comment: This fails to address the duplicate `id` problem in OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to deal with floats and for this you need to understand what [float](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)s and [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) are :

a few ways to do this, that you should understand once you been reading a bit about floats, clearing and Block formating context.

*(last example in the snippet below, oldish,  even avoids the floats but does the layout)*

```css
/* DEMO purpose :  Show the id or class being used on that container*/

section:before {
  content: attr(id)' 'attr(class);
  display: table;
  background: #177EE5;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black, 0 0 1px black;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
/* your css turned into class to be valid since used for many tags */

.container {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 990px;
}
.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}
.splitter {
  background-color: green;
  width: 90px;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}
/* wrapper for each examples */

section {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em;
}
/* different ways shown, usefull for testing only if you read about floats and dig a bit */

/* table */

.table .container {
  display: table;
}
/* overflow */

.overflow .container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* float */

.float .container {
  float: left;
}
/* flex */

.flex .container {
  display: flex;
}
/* inline-block */

.inline-block .container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
/* last examples without floats */

/*no float & ie8 */

#table div {
  float: none
}
#table #first-row,
#table > div {
  display: table-row;
}
#table > div > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
#table {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 990px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
#left {
  width: 300px;
}
#splitter {
  width: 90px;
}
#right {
  width: 200px;
}
#table > div > div {
  background-color: red;
}
#table > div > div + div {
  background-color: green;
}
#table > div > div + div + div {
  background-color: blue;
}
#table:before {
  display: table-caption;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#table > div:after {
  content: "Notice there's a gap to fill here since cols do not cover the 990px";
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<section class="your CSS :-: no BFC involved">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">A</div>
    <div class="splitter">B</div>
    <div class="right">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">D</div>
    <div class="splitter">E</div>
    <div class="right">F</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="table">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">A</div>
    <div class="splitter">B</div>
    <div class="right">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">D</div>
    <div class="splitter">E</div>
    <div class="right">F</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="overflow">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">A</div>
    <div class="splitter">B</div>
    <div class="right">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">D</div>
    <div class="splitter">E</div>
    <div class="right">F</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="float">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">A</div>
    <div class="splitter">B</div>
    <div class="right">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">D</div>
    <div class="splitter">E</div>
    <div class="right">F</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="flex">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">A</div>
    <div class="splitter">B</div>
    <div class="right">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">D</div>
    <div class="splitter">E</div>
    <div class="right">F</div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="inline-block">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">A</div>
    <div class="splitter">B</div>
    <div class="right">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">D</div>
    <div class="splitter">E</div>
    <div class="right">F</div>
  </div>
</section>
<p>another way without float including IE8 ?</p>
<section id="table" class="table">
  <div id="first-row">
    <div id="left">A</div>
    <div id="splitter">B</div>
    <div id="right">C</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

There could be more examples from the same chunks of code and floatting children.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.container{
background-color: #333333;
width:990px;
display:block;
clear:both;
}

#left{
background-color: red;
width:300px;
float:left;
}

#splitter{
background-color: green;
width:90px;
float:left;
}

#right{
background-color: blue;
width: 200px;
float:left;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">A</div>
    <div id="splitter">B</div>
    <div id="right">C</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="left">D</div>
    <div id="splitter">E</div>
    <div id="right">F</div>
</div>
</body>
```

result is

[image]

Comment: It won't work. You override display:block; to display:block;  (default for block elements)

Comment: This "solution" still has two containers with identical `id` values. Invalid HTML.

Comment: `left`, `splitter` and `right` are still duplicate `id`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want done bro..
this one is by using `display:inline-block` https://jsfiddle.net/p4domjrb/
this one is by using `float:left` https://jsfiddle.net/p4domjrb/1/

```
.container {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 990px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.left {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.splitter {
  background-color: green;
  width: 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
.right {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

don't use `id` I suggest use `class` isntead because `id`is called only once.

Comment: `margin-left: -4px;` is not the best solution to white-space related `inline-block` layout problems. Standard way to solve it is to set `.container { font-size: 0; }` and then re-set the font-size you want on the children. First solution though that doesn't fail to mention the duplicate `id`s in OP's code.